# PySpark Filter between - provide a list of upper and lower bounds, based on groups

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe and would like to filter for rows between an upper bound and lower bound.
Typically, I would just use a filter with between:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
... sql_context creation ...

pdfRaw=pd.DataFrame([{"vehicleID":'A', "Segment":'State Hwy', "speed":68.0},\
{"vehicleID":'B', "Segment":'State Hwy', "speed":76.0}])
dfRaw = sql_context.createDataFrame(pdfRaw).withColumn("vehicleID", "Segment", "speed")

dfRaw.show()

+-----------+------------+-----+
   vehicleID|     Segment|value|
+-----------+------------+-----+
|          A|   State Hwy| 68.0|
|          B|   State Hwy| 73.0|
+-----------+------------+-----+

dfRaw.filter(F.col("speed").between(70,75)).show()

+-----------+------------+-----+
   vehicleID|     Segment|value|
+-----------+------------+-----+
|          B|   State Hwy| 73.0|
+-----------+------------+-----+
```

However I have multiple speed values that I would like to filter between.

```
Speeds_Curious = {
[25,30],
[55,60],
[60,65],
[70,75]
}
```

And I actually want to take it one step further. The upper and lower bounds to the filter between depend on the result of a groupby of a previous data frame.

```
df_RoadSegments.groupby('Segment')\
.agg(F.min('SpeedLimit').alias('minSpeed'),\
F.max('SpeedLimit').alias('maxSpeed'))\
.show()

+-----------+----------+----------+
     Segment|  minSpeed|  maxSpeed|
+-----------+----------+----------+
|      Urban|      25.0|      30.0|
|  State Hwy|      55.0|      60.0|
|I-State Hwy|      60.0|      65.0|
|I-State Hwy|      70.0|      75.0|
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

So basically I would like to filter a dataframe between values that are available as columns on a different dataframe.

Something like:

```
dfLimits = df_RoadSegments.groupby('Segment')\
.agg(F.min('SpeedLimit').alias('minSpeed'),\ F.max('SpeedLimit').alias('maxSpeed'))

dfRaw.groupby('Segment')\
.filter(F.col("speed")\
.between(dfLimits.where(dfLimits.Segment=="State Hwy"(??)).select('minSpeed')),\
dfLimits.where(dfLimits.Segment=="State Hwy"(??)).select('maxSpeed'))))\
.show()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following approach will get you all the vehicles that are between the `min` and `max` speed for the particular segment that they belong to.

You can join the two dataframes:

```
df_joined = dfRaw.join(dfLimits, on="Segment", how="left")
+---------+---------+-----+--------+--------+
|  Segment|vehicleID|speed|minSpeed|maxSpeed|
+---------+---------+-----+--------+--------+
|State Hwy|        A| 68.0|      55|      60|
|State Hwy|        B| 76.0|      55|      60|
+---------+---------+-----+--------+--------+
```

If you want a further flag of whether the speed is in between rhe mentioned bounds, then you can write:

```
flag_df = df_joined.withColumn("flag", F.when((F.col("speed") > F.col("minSpeed")) & (F.col("speed") < F.col("minSpeed")), 1).otherwise(0))
flag_df.show()
+---------+---------+-----+--------+--------+----+
|  Segment|vehicleID|speed|minSpeed|maxSpeed|flag|
+---------+---------+-----+--------+--------+----+
|State Hwy|        A| 68.0|      55|      60|   0|
|State Hwy|        B| 76.0|      55|      60|   0|
+---------+---------+-----+--------+--------+----+
```

You can then simply filter on the flag saying:

```
df_final = df.filter(F.col("flag") == 1)
```

Comment: Ok, this works for the original question. But there's one more caveat. For a given "segment", there could be more than one "minSpeed" and "maxSpeed".

I have edited the question to mention two conditions for the "I-StateHwy" segment.

Comment: @penguin This will execute row-wise, just change `join="outer"` so that it duplicates the rows for segments

Comment: Oh! Yeah that should do it. Marking your response as the answer  now.